# awk -v var=$var /var/ is not working as expected

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

Portion of file:

```
 <style:style style:name="P15" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Table_20_Contents">
      <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/>
      <style:text-properties style:font-name="open sansregular2" fo:font-size="18pt" fo:font-weight="normal" officeooo:rsid="00300000" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00100000" style:font-size-asian="18pt" style:font-weight-asian="normal" style:font-size-complex="18pt" style:font-weight-complex="normal"/>
    </style:style>
    <style:style style:name="P16" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Table_20_Contents">
      <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/>
      <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="open sansregular2" fo:font-size="18pt" officeooo:rsid="00050000" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="000040000" style:font-size-asian="18pt" style:font-size-complex="18pt"/>
    </style:style>
    <style:style style:name="P17" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Table_20_Contents">
      <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/>
      <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="open sansregular" fo:font-size="18pt" officeooo:rsid="00100002" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00100002" style:font-size-asian="18pt" style:font-size-complex="18pt"/>
    </style:style>
```

```
awk '/\<style:style style:name="P16"/,/style:style\>/' RS='\</style:style\>' file
```

although probably not formed correctly, produces desired results:

```
<style:style style:name="P16" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Table_20_Contents">
      <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/>
      <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="open sansregular2" fo:font-size="18pt" officeooo:rsid="00050000" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="000040000" style:font-size-asian="18pt" style:font-size-complex="18pt"/>
```

(I want the whole block, including the `</style:style>`, but can work with as is), however,

```
echo $TPNum
"P16"
awk -v TPNum=$TPNum '/\<style:style style:name=TPNum/,/style:style\>/' RS='\</style:style\>' file
```

produces no results, other than same warning: `` awk: warning: escape sequence `\<' treated as plain `<' awk: warning: escape sequence `\>' treated as plain `>' ``.
I have used variables with awk before with no problems. What am I missing here, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is HTML or XML then you should consider using a tool that is designed for markup languages.

However if you must use `awk`, then AFAIK you can't use variables inside a *regexp constant* `/.../`. However you can use what the GNU awk user guide refers to as a [dynamic regexp or a computed regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html) - basically a string expression that you can use on the RHS of a `~` comparison. So:

```
$ TPNum='"P16"'

$ awk -v TPNum="$TPNum" '
    $0 ~ "\\<style:style style:name="TPNum{p=1} p{print} /style:style>/{p=0}
  ' file
    <style:style style:name="P16" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Table_20_Contents">
      <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false"/>
      <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="open sansregular2" fo:font-size="18pt" officeooo:rsid="00050000" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="000040000" style:font-size-asian="18pt" style:font-size-complex="18pt"/>
    </style:style>
```

The backslash needs to be escaped in the dynamic regex because the string is scanned twice:

> What difference does it make if the string is scanned twice? The
> answer has to do with escape sequences, and particularly with
> backslashes. To get a backslash into a regular expression inside a
> string, you have to type two backslashes.

Comment: I had started to use tilde but was still having some troubles.  Yours is the first I've seen about the p in ```{p=1}``` and ```p{print}```. And I hadn't thought that the string would be scanned twice. Thank you!